# Pick Random Text from an Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have made it, but is it possible to show it only one time and delete it from the list for each thing?

For example, it first shows the "first" When it's been sent, I want to send the other 3 messages, and when it's empty, it indicates that there aren't any [answers] in the list.

```
const messages = ["first", "two", "three", "four"]
const randomMessage = messages[Math.floor(Math.random() * messages.length) - 1];
```

Comment: Just filter it out after it is used

Comment: Please update your title to reflect the body more. Your title says that you want to pick a random value from the array, but you already did that. What you really want is to delete after usage.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest using a shuffling algorithm to shuffle your messages, you can then use [Array.shift()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift) to pick off messages one by one.

The `shuffle()` function here is a basic [Fisher–Yates / Knuth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) shuffle.

```js
function shuffle(arr) {
  for (let i = arr.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    [arr[i], arr[j]] = [arr[j], arr[i]];
  }
  return arr;
}

const messages = ["first", "two", "three", "four"];
const randomizedMessages = shuffle(messages);

let i = 0;
// Take messages one by one using Array.pop()
while(randomizedMessages.length) {
    console.log(`Message #${++i}:`, randomizedMessages.shift());
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Or using [lodash shuffle](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#shuffle):

```js
const messages = ["first", "two", "three", "four"];
const randomizedMessages = _.shuffle(messages);

let i = 0;
while(randomizedMessages.length) {
    console.log(`Message #${++i}:`, randomizedMessages.shift());
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Comment: Just ~25kB GZipped lib for an easy random index generator?

Comment: Of course you can use your own version, as above, or one can just pull the _.shuffle function by itself.

Comment: The second snippet does not work.

Comment: Should be fixed now, thanks for testing!

Answer (score 0):

After using it, you can find the index of the element picked, then [remove it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5767357/15781079) right after.

```js
const messages = ["first", "two", "three", "four"]
const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * messages.length)
const randomMessage = messages[index]
messages.splice(index, 1)
//rest of what you are going to do with 'randomMessage'
```

As for checking if it is empty, just check either `messages.length` or `randomMessage`. Both will be [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) if the array is empty (`messages.length` will be `0` and `randomMessage` will be `undefined`)

```js
if (!messages.length) console.log("The array is empty!")
```

Comment: You already KNOW the index! It's `Math.floor(Math.random() * messages.length) - 1`. Extract that as variable and you don't need the `indexOf` call.

Comment: Also, you don't need `- 1`, since you're calling `Math.floor`

Comment: Ok, I was just copying how the OP did it